# How many Centimorgans would be shared with half niece?

Tags: autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

My newly discovered half sister has a child.

Around how many centimorgans do you think i should share with her?

I am not looking for an exact number. I'm looking for a range.

Comment: Between 500 and 1446 cMs, according to https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl, if you're going to give an answer, perhaps it should be an Answer.

Comment: @RobertShaw, not when I'm working in a Canonical question to which this should be a duplicate. In fact there are loads of questions to which it could already be a duplicate.  And not when I'm busy with loads of other things -- there'll be somebody along in a day or so to turn my comment into their answer -- there usually is.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl.  There.

Answer (score 1):

Your half niece and you would share between 500-1446 cM, according to the [Shared cM Project](https://thegeneticgenealogist.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Relationship_Chart_FINAL_August_2017.jpg).  I always go to the original source and don't count on anything with probabilities.